# write SQL Query in the ASP.Net MVC Model class

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have this database code. I am using Asp.net MVC Code first method. so, how can I implement in my model?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[security_code_mapping_intmdt]
(
    [SOURCE_SECURITY_CODE] [VARCHAR](25) NOT NULL,
    [SECURITY_CODE] [VARCHAR](25) NOT NULL,
    [INSTRUMENT_NAME] [VARCHAR](15) NOT NULL,
    [SRC_FLAG] [VARCHAR](10) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_COMMAP_HSBC_CODE] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SOURCE_SECURITY_CODE] ASC)
)
GO
```

my question is about what should I written in my model class for making with the database with code first approches.

Comment: What is your **question**?  (hint:  "how do I....." isn't a good question.  see [ask]).

Comment: Let me google that for you: [Tutorial: Get Started with Entity Framework 6 Code First using MVC 5 - Create an Entity Framework Data Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this.

```
public class security_code_mapping_intmdt
{
    [Key]
    [StringLength(25)]
    [Required]
    public string SOURCE_SECURITY_CODE{get;set;}

    [StringLength(25)]
    [Required]
    public string SECURITY_CODE{get;set;}

    [StringLength(15)]
    [Required]
    public string INSTRUMENT_NAME{get;set;}

    [StringLength(10)]
    [Required]
    public string SRC_FLAG{get;set;}
}
```